# Star Wars API-Retrieve multiple pages of data from API with GET

Tags: python-3.x, api, loops, python-requests

I would like to retrieve all the data from an API variable. Currently I am only able to retrieve the first page but not all of them.
The API is a webpage with all the information from Star Wars. I need all the information from the characters (people).

I have the following code:
In the first part I get there is a total of 82 people. The API page has a limit of 10 results per page so there should be 8 full pages and the 9th with only 2 results:

```
#Importamos las librerias
import requests
import json
#Obtenemos la url de la API
url= requests.get("https://swapi.dev/api/people")
info=json.loads(url.content) #Transformamos a JSON el contenido
quantity=info['count'] #Extraremos la variable 'count'
print("Hay un total de",quantity, "personajes") #Imprimimos el total de personajes.
#
#Ahora el listado
#
for page in range(1,3):
    url_pages= requests.get("https://swapi.dev/api/people?page")
    lists=json.loads(url_pages.content)
    results=lists['results']
results
```

Could you help me please? If it's possible to automatically loop all the pages without knowing the exact amount of pages would be better, but something is better than nothing :)

Answer (score 0):

May be you should install [swapi-python](https://github.com/phalt/swapi-python) and run:

```
peoples = swapi.get_all("people")

for p in peoples:
    print(p.name)
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, I'm working with jupyter and I don't know if I can install modules... Isn't there other way that could work not only with this API? Because I understand swapi is specific of this API.